# SSRS Date Parameters issue - problema Parametros de fecha ssrs

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services, parameters

(My english is not perfect, im sorry)
My Problem is this, i'm using ssrs to see something from the database in a date range
When I make this query

```
SELECT
  VI.CD_CODI_MED_CIT
  ,VI.NO_NOMB_MED
  ,VI.CitasAsignadas
  ,VI.FE_FECH_CIT
  ,VI.CitasDisponibles
FROM
  Vista_Disponible_Asignada as VI
WHERE
  (VI.FE_FECH_CIT BETWEEN @FECHA_1 AND @FECHA_2) AND
  VI.NO_NOMB_MED LIKE 'JUAN ALEJANDRO SUCERQUIA'
```

There is no problem and the date parameters work fine, but when I add a new person, like

```
WHERE
 (VI.FE_FECH_CIT BETWEEN @FECHA_1 AND @FECHA_2) AND
 VI.NO_NOMB_MED LIKE 'JUAN ALEJANDRO SUCERQUIA' Or 
 VI. bla bla bla LIKE 'more bla bla bla'
```

and select a date range like a week ( 5 days ) the report shows me a huge data range, like a month. I dont know why is this happening

If u can help me i will be very happy :D 
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the placement of the OR.

```
WHERE
  (VI.FE_FECH_CIT BETWEEN @FECHA_1 AND @FECHA_2) AND
  VI.NO_NOMB_MED LIKE 'JUAN ALEJANDRO SUCERQUIA' Or 
  VI. bla bla bla LIKE 'more bla bla bla'
```

should be below to add the parenth with the OR.

```
WHERE
  (VI.FE_FECH_CIT BETWEEN @FECHA_1 AND @FECHA_2) AND
  (VI.NO_NOMB_MED LIKE 'JUAN ALEJANDRO SUCERQUIA' Or 
  VI. bla bla bla LIKE 'more bla bla bla')
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to add proper brackets '**(**', '**)**' at proper place to avoid huge date.
It should be like

```
WHERE
  (VI.FE_FECH_CIT BETWEEN @FECHA_1 AND @FECHA_2) AND
  (VI.NO_NOMB_MED LIKE 'JUAN ALEJANDRO SUCERQUIA' Or 
  VI. bla bla bla LIKE 'more bla bla bla' )
```

or

```
WHERE
  (VI.FE_FECH_CIT BETWEEN @FECHA_1 AND @FECHA_2) AND
  (VI.NO_NOMB_MED LIKE 'JUAN ALEJANDRO SUCERQUIA') Or 
  (VI. bla bla bla LIKE 'more bla bla bla')
```

It is totally depend on your requirement but please make sure that brackets are placed in proper position to get the actual result.